# Zend framework make sure that the data has been succesfully inserted into mysql

Tags: php, zend-framework

So normally you will do `mysql_affected_rows()`, but how do you do this in ZF? Here is my module snippet:

```
/**
 *
 * Inserts new user to the dabase
 * @return string|bool
 */
public function addUser($data)
{
    $newUser = $this->insert($data);
    if( $newUser ){
        return $newUser;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I don't think that If statement does the job, or I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it returns true if succes, else it would throw an exeption it the following information on this thread is right http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/How-to-test-the-success-of-Db-Table-insert-td674869.html . Try simulating an exception, a required field to be empty or smth...

Answer (score 1):

Lokk here http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.write.lastinsertid

Zend insert method return number of rows affected (usually 1).